# Conditional replacement of characters in a string pursuant to the use certain tags

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to replace characters in a text conditionally according to certain tags. For example, in the following string.

```
text <- "In Spanish, Brasil is written as <Brazil>, for some reason."
```

I would like to convert the text that is outside the angle brackets. I
currently know how to do the opposite. I can use gsub() to identify that
specific string and change some characters using the following command:

```
gsub("(<.*)z(.*?>)", "\\1s\\2", text)
[1] "In Spanish, Brasil is written as <Brasil>, for some reason."
```

But what I want to do is to change the text that is outside without affecting
the text that is within angle brackets, for example:

```
gsub("Brasil", "Brazil", text) 
[1] "In Spanish, Brazil is written as <Brazil>, for some reason."
```

Expected result, where only the text outside the angle brackets is changed:

```
[1] "In Spanish, Brazil is written as <Brazil>, for some reason."
```

How could I apply the replacement conditionally so that text within the angle
brackets is not affected? Should I need to split the string first, based on the presence of angle brackets, apply the replacements, and then merge all the strings? Or I could I just make it work with gsub() and a condition?

Comment: Just to make sure: should `<Brazil` or `Brazil>` be matched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lookarounds works too:

```
sub("(?<!<)Brasil(?!>)", "Brazil", text, perl = TRUE)
```

How this works:

- `(?<!<)`- negative lookbehind to assert that the next character to the left must **not** be a literal `<`
- `Brasil` - the literal string `Brasil`
- `(?!>)`- negative lookahead to assert that the next character to the right must **not** be literal `>`

Note that if you have a single replacement per string then `sub` suffices. If there are more than one replacements to be made, then use `gsub`.

Comment: Chris, you have a typo, `(?<!<)Brasil(?!=>)` is not correct since `=` in the lookahead is a meaningful char, `(?<!<)Brasil(?!>)` is. Besides, `Brasil` outside of angle brackets must be replaced, but with your approach, `Brasil` in `<Brasil text...` and `text Brasil> text` [will not be handled](https://regex101.com/r/vD9SMn/1).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a PCRE regex here (mind the `perl=TRUE` argument):

```r
gsub("<[^<>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|Brasil", "Brazil", text, perl=TRUE)
```

*Details*:

- `<[^<>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)` - `<`, zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`, and then `>`, and the match is failed at that position and the regex engine starts searching for the next match from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `Brasil` - a fixed char sequence.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IIFYjb/1).

If you only want to "skip" matching `Brasil` if it is *immediately* preceded with `<` and *immediately* followed with `>`, you can use

```r
gsub("(?<!<(?=\\w+>))Brasil", "Brazil", text, perl=TRUE)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IIFYjb/2). Here, `(?<!<(?=\w+>))` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if it is immediately preceded with a `<` char that is immediately followed with one or more word chars and a `>` char (i.e. if the `Brasil` is *both* preceded *and* followed with `<` and `>` chars.

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/EPLZLZ) (note I replaced `Brazil` with `Brasil` inside angle brackets for better visibility):

```r
text <- "In Spanish, Brasil is written as <Brasil>, for some reason."
gsub("<[^<>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|Brasil", "Brazil", text, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "In Spanish, Brazil is written as <Brasil>, for some reason."
text <- "In Spanish, Brasil is written as <Brasil>, for some reason."
gsub("(?<!<(?=\\w+>))Brasil", "Brazil", text, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "In Spanish, Brazil is written as <Brasil>, for some reason."
```